Filter hook for the action of listing users
I need to modify the list of users return on the 'All Users' admin page. I am producing a list by having added the list_user capability to the author role and this has produced a list of users. Now I need to modify them.
I found wp_list_users_args but this is not called. (Nor is it called in the default case when users are list in the Admin page for the Administrator).
What filter can I use to modify the list of users listed in the Admin panel on the 'All Users'  wp-admin/users.php  page?
Thanks

Just like posts with WP_Query and pre_get_posts, there is WP_User_Query and pre_get_users that lets you modify the query parameters for fetching the users. This is the most efficient method of adjusting the list of users.
e.g.

add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'justin_wylllie_pre_get_users' );
function justin_wylllie_pre_get_users( \WP_User_Query $query ): void {
    // ... modify the query object if we're on the relevant page
}


Thanks. I found that the best way to see what I could modify was to dump the query and see what I could change. Can I just ask a PHP related question? My callback does not return anything. It just modifies the query in place. This means that the query must be passed in by reference. But, I thought, in PHP, that only happens if you explicitly put a & before the param in the function definition?

the reference passing is happening in WP core, not in the function. Strictly speaking the $query variable is a copy but it's the reference that's a copy, not the object its pointing to. If this were PHP 4 then yes you'd need an ampersand but modern WordPress doesn't run on PHP 4 and it hasn't been supported for 20 years. Coincidentally PHP 4 is why people write array( &$this, when adding hooks, you can kill off that ampersand, PHP 5 and newer pass object by reference not value
